# How do I add a picture?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have parsed my RSS feed through my app. I was able to get the descriptions and stuff, but im having a hard time with adding a picture.

```jsx
import axios from "axios";
import {useEffect ,useState} from "react";
import Feed from "./Feed";
import "./news.css";

function News() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const getArticles = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/");
      setArticles(res.data);
    }catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect (()=> {
    getArticles();
  }, [])

  console.log(articles);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="newsContainer">
        <div className="head__text">
              <h1>Eco News</h1>
              <a href="/home">Return to Home</a>
        </div>
        <div className="articles">
            <div className="pics">
              <img src = "https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/YCC-Logo-website-1.png?resize=2048%2C612&ssl=1" />
            </div>
            {articles.map((item, i) =>
            <Feed 
              key = {i}
              title = {item.item.title}
              link = {item.item.link}
              date = {item.item.pubDate}
              picture = {item.item.content.src}
              content = {item.item.contentSnippet}
            />
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default News;
```

that is what I have. so far, but need help with

```
picture = {item.item.content}
```

I looked at the console log just to see where I might be able to grab the img source...

```xml
<figure><img width="300" height="169" src="https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?fit=300%2C169&amp;ssl=1" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="a photo of a woman drinking coffee and looking at a laptop" decoding="async" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?w=1600&amp;ssl=1 1600w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=300%2C169&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=1024%2C576&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=768%2C432&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=1536%2C864&amp;ssl=1 1536w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=1200%2C675&amp;ssl=1 1200w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=1568%2C882&amp;ssl=1 1568w, https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?resize=400%2C225&amp;ssl=1 400w" sizes="(max-width: 34.9rem) calc(100vw - 2rem), (max-width: 53rem) calc(8 * (100vw / 12)), (min-width: 53rem) calc(6 * (100vw / 12)), 100vw" /></figure>
<p>Content aggregators are adding Spanish-language voice-overs or subtitles to misleading content that they think can go viral. </p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://yaleclimateconnections.org/2023/03/online-misinformation-is-spreading-from-english-to-spanish/">Online misinformation is spreading from English to Spanish</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://yaleclimateconnections.org">Yale Climate Connections</a>.</p>
```

the `figure img[src]` line is what im trying to get, but i cant seem to do it

I tried

```
<> {picture} </>
```

only the link printed.

```
<img> {picture} </img>
```

nothing

[image]

Comment: Are you parsing the response into a JS data structure? Axios is good at handling JSON by default but you've got an XML document

Comment: Could please [edit] your question to show **exactly** what `console.log(articles)` shows? Use a screenshot if you can't capture it accurately in text form

Comment: Just to debug try `<img width="300" height="169" src="https://i0.wp.com/yaleclimateconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/32423_misinfo.jpg?fit=300%2C169&amp;ssl=1" />` . Remove everything else. Are you able to see image?

Answer (score -2):

you can try like this.
document.getElementById("myImg").src = item.item.content.src;
or
let imdData = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
console.log('imData', imdData);

u will get detials about the img tag.